# Is it possible to use this with Dropbox?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am looking for a way to display a a grid of thumbnails from Dropbox in some sort of gridView.

The GridView needs to be selectable i.e. the user needs to be able to select multiple images on the grid.

The other problem I have is Navigating folders.
The root folder could contain several folders as well as images.  So the Grid would need to be able to display those images as well as the folders.  The user needs to be able to click on a folder and then display the contents of that folder (images and folders).

At the miunte I am downloading the thumbnails, I guess it would be better to get the URL of the thumbnail and use that.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
// Note that pix is an ArrayList<Bitmap> pics
 // Populates the gridView with the thumbnails opened earlier
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, pics);
        // Attachs imageAdapter to gridView
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Would it make sense for me to use this Universal Image Loader?  If so, how?
Or would I be better trying to create a custom ListView or a Custom GridView?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is better to use a custom listview with a checkbox.  I don't believe this has checkboxes by default ot as an option.